# Connection Refused where I want to put my details

Tags: html, angularjs, mongodb, web

I am making a test app on MEAN stack and whenever I try to update information in my database regarding the fields, Google chrome throws Connection refused to the Url where I am posting the stuff.

Code for the controller:

```
(function() {
angular.module('TimeSuck')
.controller('EditProfileController',['Upload','$scope','$state', '$http', function(Upload, $scope, $state, $http) {
$scope.user = localStorage['Userdata'] || undefined

$scope.$watch(function(){
    return $scope.file
},function(){
    $scope.upload($scope.file);
});

$scope.upload = function(file) {
    if(file){
        Upload.upload({
            url:'api/profile/editPhoto',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {userId: $scope.user._id},
            file: file
        }).progress(function(event){
            console.log("Uploaded");
        }).success(function(data){

        }).error(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
};

$scope.updateUsername = function() {
    var request = {
        userId: $scope.user[0]._id,
        username: $scope.username
    }
    $http.post('api/profile/updateUsername', request).success(function(){
        console.log("success");
    }).error(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })
}

$scope.updateBio = function() {
    var request = {
       userId: $scope.user[0]._id,
       bio: $scope.bio
    }

    $http.post('api/profile/updateBio', request).success(function(){
        console.log("success");
    }).error(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
}

$scope.post = function() {
    console.log("successfully Posted.");
}
```

and the code for the html is here:

```
<div class="jumbotron">

<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

<div class="row">   <div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
ngf-accept="'image/*'" >Select</div> </div>

<div class="row">
<input class="form-control" ng-model="username" ng-blur="updateUsername()">

</div>

<div class="row">
<textarea class="form-control" ng-model="Bio" ng-blur="updateBio()"> </textarea>
<button type="submit" ng-click="post()"> Post </button>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have checked, which url chrome is accessing?

Comment: It is trying to access the url i provided. but it fails posting it due to connection refused

Comment: whenever I am trying to make an edit. My object is returning null